# How can i distinguish two sets one consists of 1/n and 0 and -1/n and the other one doesn't contain 0 in language of first order logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I have the set A which  consists of 1/n and 0 and -1/n and n is an arbitrary natural number, and another set just like A but without 0.
I want to distinguish these sets in language of first order logic .
But connectness is not first order and i used to try limit but i don't know how...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume that your vocabulary includes $<$. (It has to include a symbol for **some** predicate or function, because otherwise your two sets can't be distinguished by a formula.) Then you can express, in a first-order sentence, "There exists an element with no immediate successor and no immediate predecessor." That sentence is true in $A$, since $0$ has neither an immediate predecessor nor an immediate successor, but it's false when you remove $0$.